# Converting python to exe while using openpyxl

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, openpyxl

Converting python file to exe giving me an error that openpyxl not found. I was guessing that I have to use hidden import when using pyinstaller, but it did not give any difference for some reason. How can I make it work?

#### Code:

```
#test.py
from openpyxl import Workbook
import datetime
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
ws['A1'] = 42
ws.append([1, 2, 3])
ws['A2'] = datetime.datetime.now()
wb.save("sample.xlsx")
```

#### Command Line:

```
pyinstaller --hidden-import = openpyxl test.py
```

#### Result:

```
# openpyxl not found in PYZ
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
```

#### Using:

```
pyinstaller 3.4
Python 3.6.3
Windows 10
```

Comment: Here's something that might work. Try placing your test.py script in the root of the python folder, and build it from there. See if it yields any different results.  I have not used pyinstaller before so I'm not sure what might've caused this. Maybe your python isn't correctly registered on the system PATH?